# Async Await with Mocha + Axios TrobuleShooting

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, mocha.js

we are using mocha + nodejs + axios

Below is the piece of code i have , they are all in different file.

File 1 : IT block

```
   it('Perform Post Payment Actions', function () {
    postPaymentController.triggerPostPaymentActions(params);
  });
```

File 2 : Controller

```
module.exports.triggerPostPaymentActions = function (params) {
  const actions = params.postAuthActionId.split('-');  // // 'PARTIALREFUND, 50, SUCCESS - PARTIALREFUND, 50, FAIL

  Object.entries(actions).forEach(([, action]) => {
    const actionAsArray = action.split(','); // 'PARTIALREFUND, 50, SUCCESS 

    switch (actionAsArray[0]) {. // PARTIALREFUND
      case 'PARTIALREFUND':
        paymentsPartialRefundApi.submitPaymentsPartialRefundApi(actionAsArray, params);
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  });
};
```

File 3: Acutal API Call using axios

```
module.exports.submitPaymentsPartialRefundApi = async function (actionDetails, params) {

  const postOptions = {
    url: partialRefundApiUri,
    method: 'POST',
    headers: restHeaders,
    data: params.partialRefundRequest,
  };

  try {
    const response = await axios(postOptions);
    params.partialRefundResponse = response.data;
    process.env.PARTIALREFUNDRESPONSE = JSON.stringify(params.partialRefundResponse);
  } catch (err) {
    process.env.ERRORCODE = err;
    process.env.SCRIPT_STATUS = 'failure';
    process.env.PARTIALREFUNDRESPONSE = 'Partial Refund request Failed';
    throw err;
  }



};
```

PROBLEM :

When the control is passed to submitPaymentsPartialRefundApi , then it builds the request for axios but rather than waiting for the axios call , it takes the control back to the switch case. my expectation was that since i am using async await it will execute and wait till the axios call is completed but rather than completing the call it returns the control back to the switch statement and from the switch it goes back to the IT block. so i have 2 problems.
1 Its not waiting for the axios call to end
2 Its not running switch twice in loop , its goes back to IT  block and then comes back.

Solutions Tried :

I already tried using promises for this , with and without timeout but still it did not worked.
Any help on this is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`submitPaymentsPartialRefundApi` is an asynchronous function but you are not awaiting its completion in your controller.

Your code is very weird and I don't understand what it is supposed to do as you don't return anything from your controller function and your test script does not actually test anything. That being said, your controller needs to do something like the following:

```js
module.exports.triggerPostPaymentActions = function (params) {
  const actions = params.postAuthActionId.split('-');  // // 'PARTIALREFUND, 50, SUCCESS - PARTIALREFUND, 50, FAIL
  
  return Promise.all(Object.entries(actions).map(([, action]) => {
    const actionAsArray = action.split(',');

    switch (actionAsArray[0]) {
      case 'PARTIALREFUND':
        return paymentsPartialRefundApi.submitPaymentsPartialRefundApi(actionAsArray, params);
        break;
      default:
        // return something here or use Array.filter before Array.map
        break;
    }
  }));
}
```

Then your `it` block should test that the returned promise gets resolved or something...

```js
it('Perform Post Payment Actions', function () {
    return expectAsync(postPaymentController.triggerPostPaymentActions(params)).toBeResolved();
});
```